# JSON @attributes Using ionic or AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a hard time to understand how to read JSON object containing "@attributes".

**Controller:**

```
    $http.get('http://nskfix.com/dev/BettingApp/Feeds/PLFeeds.php').then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
          getdata=response.data.Competitions.Competition.Matches.Match["@attributes"];
```

**JSON Feeds**

```
    {
@attributes: {
time: "1436244726"
},
Competitions: {
Competition: {
@attributes: {
name: "Premier League",
id: "ENG_1",
season: "2015/2016",
country: "England",
country_id: "ENG"
},
Matches: {
Match: [
{
@attributes: {
match_id: "03c44f8c67d215c39ea29ca821444c55",
match_name: "Southampton-Crystal Palace",
match_date: "2016-05-15 16:00:00"
}
},
{
@attributes: {
match_id: "5a46e12304adc60ee0ee365c2a83841e",
match_name: "Stoke-West Ham",
match_date: "2016-05-15 16:00:00",
match_status: "notstarted",
}
}
```

But i have problem it doesn't feed the data.. Please Help Me!

Comment: You are making cross domain call it seems. Browsers don't allow that. Read more about it @ [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Bro,I already added Access-Control-Allow-Origin. and have no errors in chrome console. and also console.log(response); view the feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the data is read as text, so you have to parse it to make it work.

```
$http.get('http://nskfix.com/dev/BettingApp/Feeds/PLFeeds.php').then(function(response){
      var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
      var matches = data.Competitions.Competition.Matches.Match; 
      //An array of object with @attributes field
}
```

Then you can get the info of a match from the array:

```
var matchName1 = matches[0]['@attributes'].match_name;
var matchName2 = matches[1]['@attributes'].match_name;
```

For easier reading, I recommend you map all the @attribute in the `matches` array into a new array:

```
var matchFiltered = matches.map(function(item){ return item['@attributes'];  });
//Getting the properties is easier now
var matchName1 = matchFiltered[0].match_name;
```